# Question on a fairly rigorous looking proof concerning the roots of a polynomial (resultants, symmetric polynomials, Viete)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

[image]

[image]

[image]

Sorry for the big reading here. I tried to get as much on here so that it would make sense later on. Even though I put quite a bit on here, I actually just have one question about what is said near the end of this. He says "with $P$ a symmetric polynomial that vanishes whenever $x_{i} = y_{j}$ for some $i$ and $j$". Why on earth does it vanish when $x_{i} = y_{j}$? I can't seem to understand why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, if there is a common root, then there is a common factor of the polynomial and thus the resultant vanishes. Or put another way, the resultant is a multiply of the product of factors $(x_i-y_j)$ in all combinations.